# Error with generic to apply constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have these models class:

```
public abstract class ModelBase<T>
{
   public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public class Table: ModelBase<int>
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is when I need to work with my repository and I need the type is `Table` and put the type parameters or constraints:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> 
         : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity 
         : ModelBase<T> //I know there's a mistake, but as it is needed
```

How I can do that infers the type that is in `Table` in this case is `int` or a reference to it?

`TEntity` in this case is `Table`

Comment: Why not to use `ModelBase<int>`?

Comment: @AntP I cann't simply put `ModelBase` because it requires a `type`, but I can not know what the guy who got in `Table` because I have many tables

Comment: @RohitVats because in this case I need to create one repository class for each type

Comment: @andresdescalzo: how many variants of `T` do you expect in your database?

Comment: @Dennis I know, few are type 2 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution simple to implement. I create a class `ModelBaseIdentity<T>` that resolve my problem:

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
   // code
}

public abstract class ModelBaseIdentity<T>: ModelBase
{
   public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public class Table: ModelBaseIdentity<int>
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Repository<TEntity> 
         : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity 
         : ModelBase
```

Answer (score 4):

You were pretty close. In order to use `T` in your example, you need to provide that type. In order to provide the type, it needs to be passed to the class constructor so it needs to be in the definition. You can include it as  like this

```
public class Repository<TEntity,T> 
                              //^ Include the type in the definition
     : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity 
     : ModelBase<T>
```

and now when you instantiate you need to pass both the table, and the table's type

```
var repo = new Repository<Table,int>();
```

Comment: I already thought about this alternative, but would need my service layer all types of "ID" for each table, and does not seem a good solution.

Comment: @andresdescalzo - The way you have designed the ID requires that its type be passed in this fashion.

Comment: This approach seems like it would the cleanest and most straight forward to implement on top of your schema.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that you won't have any significant number of variants for primary keys. So, you can easily do this:

```
public class TableWithIntId : ModelBase<int>
{
}

public class TableWithGuidId : ModelBase<Guid>
{
}

public class Repository<TEntity, T> : IRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : ModelBase<T>
{
}

public class TableWithIntIdRepository<TTable> : Repository<TTable, int>
    where TTable : TableWithIntId
{
}

public class TableWithGuidIdRepository<TTable> : Repository<TTable, Guid>
    where TTable : TableWithGuidId
{
}
```

This brings you into situation, when you need a `Repository` descendant for every `T`, but not for every entity.